# How do I remove the empty tweets using filter() in pyspark?

Tags: mongodb, filter, pyspark, tweets

How do I remove the empty tweets using `filter()` in pyspark? I have done the following

```
tweets = sc.textFile(.....)
tweets.count()
```

the result gives me 13995. However when I imported the data from mongodb, it showed 11186

I can't seem to apply the `filter()` command for removing the empty tweets. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

If your data like this

```
tweets = sc.parallelize(["title1", "", "title2", "title3", ""])
```

you can use `len(x)` as the filter condition:

```
tweets.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0).count()
```