# Pyspark filter out empty lists using .filter()

Tags: python-2.7, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe where one column is filled with list, either containing entries or just empty lists. I want to efficiently filter out all rows that contain empty lists.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
df.filter(sf.col('column_with_lists') != [])
```

returns me the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o303.notEqual.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class
```

Perhaps I can check the length of the list and impose it should be > 0 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504810/how-do-i-remove-the-empty-tweets-using-filter-in-pyspark)). However, I am unsure how this syntax works if I am using pyspark-sql and if `filter` even allows a lambda.

Perhaps to make clear, I have multiple columns but want to apply the above filter on a single one, removing all entries. The linked SO example filters on a single column.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So it appears it is as simple as using the size function from `sql.functions`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
df.filter(sf.size('column_with_lists') > 0)
```

Comment: What is `sf` here?

Comment: @derricw The `functions` (`pyspark.sql.functions` to be precise) module .